# Running background task synchronously in python (possibly celery/rabbitmq?)

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, background-process

I need to setup my application where I can run various background processes synchronously. For example, I have taskA1, taskA2, taskB1, and taskB2.

I want to throw them all into the background at the same time, but it would execute taskA1 and taskB1 in any order, but it can only do A2 after A1 is comlpete, or B2 after B1 is complete. As well while A1 is running, a new task A3 may be put into the queue, and that should be run only after A1 is complete (can either go after A1, or go after A2) but any A task can only be run one at a time (or same for B tasks)

Is there a good way to do this? I have celery/rabbitmq for queues, can I do it in there?

Comment: Does completion of A1 always result in A2/A3?

Answer (score 0):

You need a framework that lets you define task dependencies. Celery seems to support that http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html. Alternatively, you could write a custom wrapper/helper that handles the task dependencies in your application.